# Unable to Install anti viruses on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, anti-virus, avast

I tried installing avast on my pc this morning and uninstalling MCafee which expired but I got the error message for both situations saying : "An administrator has blocked you from running this app. For more information contact the administrator". It's my PC and I'm the only user on it. After some research I discovered what was "possibly blocking it". I went to Control Panel>Network and internet>Internet Options>Content>Certificates. Under the untrusted publishers was a list of all common antivirus applications including avast antivirus, but then the remove button is disabled. How can I enable the button? or how can I solve my antivirus problem?. Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: Are you installing the application as an Administrator.  if you are connected to a domain, then the account in question, must also be a Administrator on the domain.  Update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your system may have been a victim of the Vonteera adware. Try to use MSRT to remove it.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mmpc/2016/03/09/msrt-march-2016-vonteera/

> More recent versions of Vonteera began adding legitimate certificates that belong to a number of security and antimalware products to the untrusted certificates list...